# How to modify precompiled ASP.NET web site? Visual Studio complains that site is precompiled

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

I have a web application on ASP.NET (C#) that has some precompiled components. I've been supporting it with no problems from quite sometime, adding features and extending. Right now I am facing another extension that requires calling a remote SOAP service.

I've tried doing it according to some recommendations that I got here - via adding Web Reference, creating proxy class and all that, but Visual complains that app is precompiled.

Here is the actual output of compiler:

> The directory
>   '/trxv/App_WebReferences/' is not
>   allowed because the application is
>   precompiled. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Web.HttpException: The
>   directory '/trxv/App_WebReferences/'
>   is not allowed because the application
>   is precompiled.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The
>   directory '/trxv/App_WebReferences/'
>   is not allowed because the application
>   is precompiled.]
>   System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType,
>   String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories, Boolean
>   isDirectoryAllowed) +8805619
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType,
>   String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories) +128
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebRefDirectory()
>   +31    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   +312
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The
>   directory '/trxv/App_WebReferences/'
>   is not allowed because the application
>   is precompiled.]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +58    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   +512    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost,
>   IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory,
>   HostingEnvironmentParameters
>   hostingParameters) +729
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The
>   directory '/trxv/App_WebReferences/'
>   is not allowed because the application
>   is precompiled.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8886319
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +85
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest
>   wr) +259
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

Are there any other more or less simple(i.e. high level) methods of calling SOAP client, that would not require recompilation? Unfortunately original source code for the system is not available.

Comment: I think you've got a more general problem: how to extend a web site that is precompiled, but you don't have the source. This isn't just a web service issue.

Comment: Sort of.. the thing is that it has couple of components that it uses that are precompiled and used in the Master template. I am not touching those. I am just creating a new page, with a new form that does some remote soap calls... I can go all the way down to openning HTTP connection and talking XML directly to the service, but I hope .NET has some better/smarter ways of achieving this.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to be about not being able to change the precompiled site. I doubt the problem is really specific to web services. Broadening the question will get you more attention - I'm sure there are more ASP.NET devs than web services devs. Finally, consider WCF, as Microsoft now considers ASMX to be "legacy software".

Comment: Ok, could you give step by step detail showing exactly when VS complains? Also please post all the error messages, and check the Output and Error windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex,

Note my most recent edit. The issue has to do with the fact that you do not have a Web Application - you have a Web Site. They are unique, and strange.

I never use them unless I have to, so I've actually never seen this exception. It does seem rather final, though. So here's how you'll have to fix this:

Create a separate class library project. Add the web reference to the class library, and build it. Then, see if you can reference the class library in your web pages. The class library should contain the proxy classes.

Comment: John, that's a great idea! Thanks a lot!
I will do that and see what happens :)
Will keep this question open, just in case.